# php/mysql start the day of the week on wednesday and last day of the week on tuesday

Tags: php, mysql

I am workin on a schedule script where the start of the week is on Wednesday and the end is Tuesday. I have been researching all over and find how to start the week on wednesday but the last day always ends on saturday or sunday depending on using DAYOFWEEK or WEEKDAY.

my code is as is right now for each of the seven days...

```
                <td class="hours" colspan="2">
            <?php $hour3 = mysql_query("SELECT h.* FROM hours AS h, employees AS e 
                                        WHERE h.s_id = '" .$s_id. "' AND e.u_id = h.u_id AND DAYOFWEEK(h.date) = 4
                                        ORDER BY e.emp_id ASC");
            while($time3 = mysql_fetch_array($hour3)) { ?>

                <div class="hours">
                    <?php $starting = date("g:ia", strtotime($time3['timestart']));
                        $ending = date("g:ia", strtotime($time3['timeend']));
                            if ($time3['work'] == '1') {
                                if ($time3['why_off'] == '1') 
                                    {echo "<div class='off'>OFF [R]</div>";}
                                elseif ($time3['why_off'] == '2') 
                                    {echo "<div class='off'>OFF [ML]</div>";}
                                elseif  ($time3['why_off'] == '0')
                                    {echo "<div class='off'>OFF</div>";}
                            }
                                elseif ($time3['work'] == '0') {
                                    if ($time3['work_type'] == '1') {
                                        if ($time3['timeend'] == '23:00:00')
                                        {echo "<div class='working_w'>".$starting." - Close<br>[TL]</div>";}
                                            else {echo "<div class='working_w'>".$starting." - ".$ending."<br>[TL]</div>";}
                                    }
                                    elseif ($time3['work_type'] == '2') {
                                        if ($time3['timeend'] == '23:00:00')
                                        {echo "<div class='working_w'>".$starting." - Close<br>[SF]</div>";}
                                            else {echo "<div class='working_w'>".$starting." - ".$ending."<br>[SF]</div>";}
                                    }
                                    elseif ($time3['work_type'] == '3') {
                                        if ($time3['timeend'] == '23:00:00')
                                        {echo "<div class='working_w'>".$starting." - Close<br>[-/+]</div>";}
                                            else {echo "<div class='working_w'>".$starting." - ".$ending."<br>[-/+]</div>";}
                                    }
                                    elseif ($time3['work_type'] == '4') {
                                        if ($time3['timeend'] == '23:00:00')
                                        {echo "<div class='working_w'>".$starting." - Close<br>[TR]</div>";}
                                            else {echo "<div class='working_w'>".$starting." - ".$ending."<br>[TR]</div>";}
                                    }
                                    elseif ($time3['work_type'] == '0') {
                                        if ($time3['timeend'] == '23:00:00')
                                        {echo "<div class='working_w'>".$starting." - Close</div>";}
                                            else {echo "<div class='working_w'>".$starting." - ".$ending."</div>";}
                                    }
                                }?>

                </div>
                <?php } ?>

            </td>
            <td class="hours" colspan="2">
            <?php $hour4 = mysql_query("SELECT h.* FROM hours AS h, employees AS e 
                                        WHERE h.s_id = '" .$s_id. "' AND e.u_id = h.u_id AND DAYOFWEEK(h.date) = 5 
                                        ORDER BY e.emp_id ASC");
            while($time4 = mysql_fetch_array($hour4)) { ?>

                <div class="hours">
                    <?php $starting = date("g:ia", strtotime($time4['timestart']));
                        $ending = date("g:ia", strtotime($time4['timeend']));
                            if ($time4['work'] == '1') {
                                if ($time4['why_off'] == '1') 
                                    {echo "<div class='off'>OFF [R]</div>";}
                                elseif ($time4['why_off'] == '2') 
                                    {echo "<div class='off'>OFF [ML]</div>";}
                                elseif  ($time4['why_off'] == '0')
                                    {echo "<div class='off'>OFF</div>";}
                            }
                                elseif ($time4['work'] == '0') {
                                    if ($time4['work_type'] == '1') {
                                        if ($time4['timeend'] == '23:00:00')
                                        {echo "<div class='working_w'>".$starting." - Close<br>[TL]</div>";}
                                            else {echo "<div class='working_w'>".$starting." - ".$ending."<br>[TL]</div>";}
                                    }
                                    elseif ($time4['work_type'] == '2') {
                                        if ($time4['timeend'] == '23:00:00')
                                        {echo "<div class='working_w'>".$starting." - Close<br>[SF]</div>";}
                                            else {echo "<div class='working_w'>".$starting." - ".$ending."<br>[SF]</div>";}
                                    }
                                    elseif ($time4['work_type'] == '3') {
                                        if ($time4['timeend'] == '23:00:00')
                                        {echo "<div class='working_w'>".$starting." - Close<br>[-/+]</div>";}
                                            else {echo "<div class='working_w'>".$starting." - ".$ending."<br>[-/+]</div>";}
                                    }
                                    elseif ($time4['work_type'] == '4') {
                                        if ($time4['timeend'] == '23:00:00')
                                        {echo "<div class='working_w'>".$starting." - Close<br>[TR]</div>";}
                                            else {echo "<div class='working_w'>".$starting." - ".$ending."<br>[TR]</div>";}
                                    }
                                    elseif ($time4['work_type'] == '0') {
                                        if ($time4['timeend'] == '23:00:00')
                                        {echo "<div class='working_w'>".$starting." - Close</div>";}
                                            else {echo "<div class='working_w'>".$starting." - ".$ending."</div>";}
                                    }
                                }?>

                </div>
                <?php } ?>

            </td>
            <td class="hours" colspan="2">
            <?php $hour5 = mysql_query("SELECT h.* FROM hours AS h, employees AS e 
                                        WHERE h.s_id = '" .$s_id. "' AND e.u_id = h.u_id AND DAYOFWEEK(h.date) = 6 
                                        ORDER BY e.emp_id ASC");
            while($time5 = mysql_fetch_array($hour5)) { ?>

                <div class="hours">
                    <?php $starting = date("g:ia", strtotime($time5['timestart']));
                        $ending = date("g:ia", strtotime($time5['timeend']));
                            if ($time5['work'] == '1') {
                                if ($time5['why_off'] == '1') 
                                    {echo "<div class='off'>OFF [R]</div>";}
                                elseif ($time5['why_off'] == '2') 
                                    {echo "<div class='off'>OFF [ML]</div>";}
                                elseif  ($time5['why_off'] == '0')
                                    {echo "<div class='off'>OFF</div>";}
                            }
                                elseif ($time5['work'] == '0') {
                                    if ($time5['work_type'] == '1') {
                                        if ($time5['timeend'] == '23:00:00')
                                        {echo "<div class='working_w'>".$starting." - Close<br>[TL]</div>";}
                                            else {echo "<div class='working_w'>".$starting." - ".$ending."<br>[TL]</div>";}
                                    }
                                    elseif ($time5['work_type'] == '2') {
                                        if ($time5['timeend'] == '23:00:00')
                                        {echo "<div class='working_w'>".$starting." - Close<br>[SF]</div>";}
                                            else {echo "<div class='working_w'>".$starting." - ".$ending."<br>[SF]</div>";}
                                    }
                                    elseif ($time5['work_type'] == '3') {
                                        if ($time5['timeend'] == '23:00:00')
                                        {echo "<div class='working_w'>".$starting." - Close<br>[-/+]</div>";}
                                            else {echo "<div class='working_w'>".$starting." - ".$ending."<br>[-/+]</div>";}
                                    }
                                    elseif ($time5['work_type'] == '4') {
                                        if ($time5['timeend'] == '23:00:00')
                                        {echo "<div class='working_w'>".$starting." - Close<br>[TR]</div>";}
                                            else {echo "<div class='working_w'>".$starting." - ".$ending."<br>[TR]</div>";}
                                    }
                                    elseif ($time5['work_type'] == '0') {
                                        if ($time5['timeend'] == '23:00:00')
                                        {echo "<div class='working_w'>".$starting." - Close</div>";}
                                            else {echo "<div class='working_w'>".$starting." - ".$ending."</div>";}
                                    }
                                }?>

                </div>
                <?php } ?>

            </td>
            <td class="hours" colspan="2">
            <?php $hour6 = mysql_query("SELECT h.* FROM hours AS h, employees AS e 
                                        WHERE h.s_id = '" .$s_id. "' AND e.u_id = h.u_id AND DATE_ADD((DAYOFWEEK(h.date) = 7), INTERVAL 7 DAY)
                                        ORDER BY e.emp_id ASC");
            while($time6 = mysql_fetch_array($hour6)) { ?>

                <div class="hours">
                    <?php $starting = date("g:ia", strtotime($time6['timestart']));
                        $ending = date("g:ia", strtotime($time6['timeend']));
                            if ($time6['work'] == '1') {
                                if ($time6['why_off'] == '1') 
                                    {echo "<div class='off'>OFF [R]</div>";}
                                elseif ($time6['why_off'] == '2') 
                                    {echo "<div class='off'>OFF [ML]</div>";}
                                elseif  ($time6['why_off'] == '0')
                                    {echo "<div class='off'>OFF</div>";}
                            }
                                elseif ($time6['work'] == '0') {
                                    if ($time6['work_type'] == '1') {
                                        if ($time6['timeend'] == '23:00:00')
                                        {echo "<div class='working_w'>".$starting." - Close<br>[TL]</div>";}
                                            else {echo "<div class='working_w'>".$starting." - ".$ending."<br>[TL]</div>";}
                                    }
                                    elseif ($time6['work_type'] == '2') {
                                        if ($time6['timeend'] == '23:00:00')
                                        {echo "<div class='working_w'>".$starting." - Close<br>[SF]</div>";}
                                            else {echo "<div class='working_w'>".$starting." - ".$ending."<br>[SF]</div>";}
                                    }
                                    elseif ($time6['work_type'] == '3') {
                                        if ($time6['timeend'] == '23:00:00')
                                        {echo "<div class='working_w'>".$starting." - Close<br>[-/+]</div>";}
                                            else {echo "<div class='working_w'>".$starting." - ".$ending."<br>[-/+]</div>";}
                                    }
                                    elseif ($time6['work_type'] == '4') {
                                        if ($time6['timeend'] == '23:00:00')
                                        {echo "<div class='working_w'>".$starting." - Close<br>[TR]</div>";}
                                            else {echo "<div class='working_w'>".$starting." - ".$ending."<br>[TR]</div>";}
                                    }
                                    elseif ($time6['work_type'] == '0') {
                                        if ($time6['timeend'] == '23:00:00')
                                        {echo "<div class='working_w'>".$starting." - Close</div>";}
                                            else {echo "<div class='working_w'>".$starting." - ".$ending."</div>";}
                                    }
                                }?>

                </div>
                <?php } ?>

            </td>
            <td class="hours" colspan="2">
            <?php $hour0 = mysql_query("SELECT h.* FROM hours AS h, employees AS e 
                                        WHERE h.s_id = '" .$s_id. "' AND e.u_id = h.u_id AND DATE_ADD((DAYOFWEEK(h.date) = 1), INTERVAL 7 DAY)
                                        ORDER BY e.emp_id ASC");
            while($time0 = mysql_fetch_array($hour0)) { ?>

                <div class="hours">
                    <?php $starting = date("g:ia", strtotime($time0['timestart']));
                        $ending = date("g:ia", strtotime($time0['timeend']));
                            if ($time0['work'] == '1') {
                                if ($time0['why_off'] == '1')
                                    {echo "<div class='off'>OFF [R]</div>";}
                                elseif ($time0['why_off'] == '2')
                                    {echo "<div class='off'>OFF [ML]</div>";}
                                elseif  ($time0['why_off'] == '0')
                                    {echo "<div class='off'>OFF</div>";}
                            }
                                elseif ($time0['work'] == '0') {
                                    if ($time0['work_type'] == '1') {
                                        if ($time0['timeend'] == '23:00:00')
                                        {echo "<div class='working_w'>".$starting." - Close<br>[TL]</div>";}
                                            else {echo "<div class='working_w'>".$starting." - ".$ending."<br>[TL]</div>";}
                                    }
                                    elseif ($time0['work_type'] == '2') {
                                        if ($time0['timeend'] == '23:00:00')
                                        {echo "<div class='working_w'>".$starting." - Close<br>[SF]</div>";}
                                            else {echo "<div class='working_w'>".$starting." - ".$ending."<br>[SF]</div>";}
                                    }
                                    elseif ($time0['work_type'] == '3') {
                                        if ($time0['timeend'] == '23:00:00')
                                        {echo "<div class='working_w'>".$starting." - Close<br>[-/+]</div>";}
                                            else {echo "<div class='working_w'>".$starting." - ".$ending."<br>[-/+]</div>";}
                                    }
                                    elseif ($time0['work_type'] == '4') {
                                        if ($time0['timeend'] == '23:00:00')
                                        {echo "<div class='working_w'>".$starting." - Close<br>[TR]</div>";}
                                            else {echo "<div class='working_w'>".$starting." - ".$ending."<br>[TR]</div>";}
                                    }
                                    elseif ($time0['work_type'] == '0') {
                                        if ($time0['timeend'] == '23:00:00')
                                        {echo "<div class='working_w'>".$starting." - Close</div>";}
                                            else {echo "<div class='working_w'>".$starting." - ".$ending."</div>";}
                                    }
                                }?>

                </div>
                <?php } ?>

            </td>
            <td class="hours" colspan="2">
            <?php $hour1 = mysql_query("SELECT h.* FROM hours AS h, employees AS e 
                                        WHERE h.s_id = '" .$s_id. "' AND e.u_id = h.u_id AND DATE_ADD((DAYOFWEEK(h.date) = 2), INTERVAL 7 DAY)
                                        ORDER BY e.emp_id ASC");
            while($time1 = mysql_fetch_array($hour1)) { ?>

                <div class="hours">
                    <?php $starting = date("g:ia", strtotime($time1['timestart']));
                        $ending = date("g:ia", strtotime($time1['timeend']));
                            if ($time1['work'] == '1') {
                                if ($time1['why_off'] == '1') 
                                    {echo "<div class='off'>OFF [R]</div>";}
                                elseif ($time1['why_off'] == '2') 
                                    {echo "<div class='off'>OFF [ML]</div>";}
                                elseif  ($time1['why_off'] == '0')
                                    {echo "<div class='off'>OFF</div>";}
                            }
                                elseif ($time1['work'] == '0') {
                                    if ($time1['work_type'] == '1') {
                                        if ($time1['timeend'] == '23:00:00')
                                        {echo "<div class='working_w'>".$starting." - Close<br>[TL]</div>";}
                                            else {echo "<div class='working_w'>".$starting." - ".$ending."<br>[TL]</div>";}
                                    }
                                    elseif ($time1['work_type'] == '2') {
                                        if ($time1['timeend'] == '23:00:00')
                                        {echo "<div class='working_w'>".$starting." - Close<br>[SF]</div>";}
                                            else {echo "<div class='working_w'>".$starting." - ".$ending."<br>[SF]</div>";}
                                    }
                                    elseif ($time1['work_type'] == '3') {
                                        if ($time1['timeend'] == '23:00:00')
                                        {echo "<div class='working_w'>".$starting." - Close<br>[-/+]</div>";}
                                            else {echo "<div class='working_w'>".$starting." - ".$ending."<br>[-/+]</div>";}
                                    }
                                    elseif ($time1['work_type'] == '4') {
                                        if ($time1['timeend'] == '23:00:00')
                                        {echo "<div class='working_w'>".$starting." - Close<br>[TR]</div>";}
                                            else {echo "<div class='working_w'>".$starting." - ".$ending."<br>[TR]</div>";}
                                    }
                                    elseif ($time1['work_type'] == '0') {
                                        if ($time1['timeend'] == '23:00:00')
                                        {echo "<div class='working_w'>".$starting." - Close</div>";}
                                            else {echo "<div class='working_w'>".$starting." - ".$ending."</div>";}
                                    }
                                }?>

                </div>
                <?php } ?>

            </td>
            <td class="hoursboth" colspan="2">
            <?php $hour2 = mysql_query("SELECT h.* FROM hours AS h, employees AS e 
                                        WHERE h.s_id = '" .$s_id. "' AND e.u_id = h.u_id AND DATE_ADD((DAYOFWEEK(h.date) = 3), INTERVAL 7 DAY)
                                        ORDER BY e.emp_id ASC");
            while($time2 = mysql_fetch_array($hour2)) { ?>

                <div class="hours">
                    <?php $starting = date("g:ia", strtotime($time2['timestart']));
                        $ending = date("g:ia", strtotime($time2['timeend']));
                            if ($time2['work'] == '1') {
                                if ($time2['why_off'] == '1') 
                                    {echo "<div class='off'>OFF [R]</div>";}
                                elseif ($time2['why_off'] == '2') 
                                    {echo "<div class='off'>OFF [ML]</div>";}
                                elseif  ($time2['why_off'] == '0')
                                    {echo "<div class='off'>OFF</div>";}
                            }
                            elseif ($time2['work'] == '0') {
                                if ($time2['work_type'] == '1') {
                                    if ($time2['timeend'] == '23:00:00')
                                    {echo "<div class='working_w'>".$starting." - Close<br>[TL]</div>";}
                                        else {echo "<div class='working_w'>".$starting." - ".$ending."<br>[TL]</div>";}
                                }
                                elseif ($time2['work_type'] == '2') {
                                    if ($time2['timeend'] == '23:00:00')
                                    {echo "<div class='working_w'>".$starting." - Close<br>[SF]</div>";}
                                        else {echo "<div class='working_w'>".$starting." - ".$ending."<br>[SF]</div>";}
                                }
                                elseif ($time2['work_type'] == '3') {
                                    if ($time2['timeend'] == '23:00:00')
                                    {echo "<div class='working_w'>".$starting." - Close<br>[-/+]</div>";}
                                        else {echo "<div class='working_w'>".$starting." - ".$ending."<br>[-/+]</div>";}
                                }
                                elseif ($time2['work_type'] == '4') {
                                    if ($time2['timeend'] == '23:00:00')
                                    {echo "<div class='working_w'>".$starting." - Close<br>[TR]</div>";}
                                        else {echo "<div class='working_w'>".$starting." - ".$ending."<br>[TR]</div>";}
                                }
                                elseif ($time2['work_type'] == '0') {
                                    if ($time2['timeend'] == '23:00:00')
                                    {echo "<div class='working_w'>".$starting." - Close</div>";}
                                        else {echo "<div class='working_w'>".$starting." - ".$ending."</div>";}
                                }
                            }?>

                </div>
                <?php } ?>

            </td>
```

I would like to thank whomever in advance for any help given!

Comment: Wow. That's one hell of a series of if blocks. Can't you just apply an offset to each day. You know that Sunday is what is considered the week start, so shift everything by a constant offset of 3.

Comment: yeah, I've tried...
I made extra schedule times in a previous week and when I do the offset it shows either nothing or the previous week

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> how to start the week on wednesday

So basically you just want to “shift” a range of values ranging from `0` to `6` by a given number … well that’s really easy:

```
$shifted_value = ( $actual_value + $offset ) % $number_of_values;
```

So here `$offset` would be 4 (Wednesday is day #3 of the week in PHP, but *subtracting* 3 could lead to unwanted negative values with the modulo division – so we just shift the “into the future” instead of into the past, by *adding* 4 [=7-3]) and `$number_of_values` would be 7.

This would be the PHP version, in MySQL it can be done the same way – only the offset has to be adapted accordingly to the fact that for MySQL Wednesday is day #2 of the week.

Comment: so I'd put that into mysql select how?
      $thursday =  mysql_query("SELECT h.timestart, h.timeend, h.work, h.why_off, h.work_type, h.date FROM hours AS h, employees AS e 
      WHERE h.s_id = '" .$s_id. "' AND e.u_id = h.u_id AND DAYOFWEEK(h.date) = 5
      GROUP BY e.emp_id
      ORDER BY e.emp_id ASC");

Comment: I see now that you seem to be making a single query for every (working) weekday – that’s rather complicated, you should maybe use the “shifted value” as a second (or first, depending on how you want to loop over the data) ORDER BY criterion instead of putting it into the WHERE clause, so you can get the relevant data for _all_ weekdays in _one_ query.

Answer (score 0):

What about substracting some days from the date and selecting the resulting week?

```
SELECT h.* FROM hours AS h, employees AS e 
WHERE h.s_id = '" .$s_id. "' AND e.u_id = h.u_id AND 
    WEEK(DATE_ADD(h.date, INTERVAL -3 DAY)) = 4
ORDER BY h.date, e.emp_id ASC
```

Comment: The date functions are available in [MySQL 4.1](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add). Cant you do `ORDER BY DAYOFWEEK(DATE_ADD(h.date, INTERVAL -3 DAY)), e.emp_id` to sort all all empoyees by day of week?